# how to run a laravel function and pass field val through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

hey I want to run a function in my controller using the $.get to pass what is the cod that I want to execute my querys then create my excel file

my route, that's working if I type in adreess bar of my browser my file downloads.

```
Route::get('relatorios/exportar', array('as' => 'relatorios.exportar', 'uses' => 'ReportsController@exportar'));
```

my controller: note that works if i change Input::get('cod') to any number

```
public function exportar()
    {   
        $cod = Input::get('cod');  

        set_time_limit(0);
        $datainicio = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_inicio'); 
        $datafinal  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_fim');
        $mes  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('mes_referencia'); 

        $horarioQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
                            ->whereBetween('data', array($datainicio, $datafinal))
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->orderBy('cod_funcionario')
                            ->orderBy('data', 'ASC')
                            ->get();

        $horarios = reset($horarioQuery);

        $nome = 'Marcações'.$mes.'-'.Carbon::now()->year;

        $this->horario->allToExcel($nome, $horarios);
    }
```

my JS: the console log shows the right number but nothing happens

```
$('#exportar').on('click', function(){
      var cod = $("#cod").val();
      $.get('exportar', {cod: cod},  function(data) {   
        console.log(cod);     
      });
  });
```

my view:

(edited) Hi! sorry I just could see right now. how my form would be ? i did like this:

```
  {{Form::open(array("exportar","id"=>"ajaxForm"))}}
  {{ Form::submit('Exportar', array('id' => 'exportar', 'class' => 'exportar')) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('cod', $cod, array('id' => 'cod', 'class' => 'cod')) }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

I want to pass the COD in the hidden field to the generate the file, my funcition works I just need to pass this number and dont know what's happening.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there fellow Laraveller!

At first please use POST, not GET! This means you have to change your route to Route::post...

After that use AJAX, not get like this:

```
$(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: url,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $(".preloaderContainer").fadeIn(); // example
            }

        }).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        }).fail(function() {
                console.log(response);

   });
```

So the trick in here is the following:

On submitting your form we need to catch the event 'e' and prevent the page from going to that controller by `e.preventDefault();`

After that the serialize method gets all iputs fields information and their names and creates query string that is posted to the certain url (method)
and the 'url' variable gets information from the forms attribute 'action'!

In your Method you should do this to check if everything is okay:

```
$inputs = Input::except('_token');
 return Response::json($inputs);
```

Regards and tell me if you need any other help and explanation!

Comment: i'v edited my form above, its that right cuz i'm getting back to the last page and nothing happens

Comment: I found this in maatwebsite plugin:
As far as I know, it's not possible to set the download headers when doing an ajax request.
i think that is my problem

Comment: I got the idea, but I found another way to do, thx so much for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

that worked

I gave up from using ajax and just tried with routes

```
Route::get('relatorios/exportar/{cod}', array('as' => 'relatorios.exportar', 'uses' => 'ReportsController@exportar'));
```

my controller

```
 public function exportar($cod)
    {   
        set_time_limit(0);
        $datainicio = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_inicio'); 
        $datafinal  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('periodo_fim');
        $mes  = DB::table('tb_periodo')->where('cod', $cod)->pluck('mes_referencia'); 

        $horarioQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
                            ->whereBetween('data', array($datainicio, $datafinal))
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->orderBy('cod_funcionario')
                            ->orderBy('data', 'ASC')
                            ->get();

        $horarios = reset($horarioQuery);

        $nome = 'Marcações'.$mes.'-'.Carbon::now()->year;

        $this->horario->allToExcel($nome, $horarios);
    }
```

view:

```
{{ link_to_route('relatorios.exportar', 'Exportar para excel', array($cod), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```

that's solved for me, because dont load another page and download the correct file.
thx for the help!!